# Are these Canon websites safe to download printer software?

Tags: printing, driver

I'd like some drivers for printer. Is Canon site safe to download them as self-installed trojans are Mac's worst nightmare and I have no real time scanner to detect if something comes in.

Google gives me both sites, but is there any difference?

https://www.usa.canon.com

http://www.canon-europe.com

I just find it weird one is canon.com while other canon-europe.com - if it is same company, shouldn't it be europe.canon.com...

Not sure what to trust or to trust either at all. 
And connecting printer to Mac will not offer download so I need this...

Comment: Yes it's legitimate. Both sites link to each other in their sites. If you choose one site and change your location to the other site, it'll send you there.

Comment: usa.canon.com is legitimate. Note the https, also did a whois and it's registered to canon (of course it is, it's just canon.com). Not sure about canon-europe.com, that's a weird one (also note the lack of https).

Comment: @owlswipe Good point, didn't notice that myself. Yeah, europe one looks shabby too. I'll be using US one then. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can check the signature/authenticity of a downloaded package installer (*.pkg) quickly yourself - independent of the shabby look of a website:

Open Terminal and enter `pkgutil --check-signature`. Then open the downloaded dmg image and drop the pkg onto the Terminal window and hit the enter key:

```
pkgutil --check-signature  /Volumes/PrinterDriver_MG8100\ series/PrinterDriver_MG8100\ series_161000.pkg 
Package "PrinterDriver_MG8100 series_161000.pkg":
   Status: signed by a certificate trusted by Mac OS X
   Certificate Chain:
    1. Developer ID Installer: Canon Inc.
       SHA1 fingerprint: 5B B8 FC D3 38 4C CA 03 CD B6 14 EE 1B 01 34 A7 75 A2 82 58
       -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    2. Developer ID Certification Authority
       SHA1 fingerprint: 3B 16 6C 3B 7D C4 B7 51 C9 FE 2A FA B9 13 56 41 E3 88 E1 86
       -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    3. Apple Root CA
       SHA1 fingerprint: 61 1E 5B 66 2C 59 3A 08 FF 58 D1 4A E2 24 52 D1 98 DF 6C 60
```

---

You get a more OS X GUI like approach by simply clicking the lock in the upper left after opening the pkg with Installer.app:

[image]

[image]

[Valid SHA1 fingerprints](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202369) for Apple updates are

```
SHA1 FA 02 79 0F CE 9D 93 00 89 C8 C2 51 0B BC 50 B4 85 8E 6F BF
SHA1 9C 86 47 71 48 B3 D7 04 24 7A 3C 3F 56 EA 2D E5 94 4B 01 C2
```

for third party software signed by an Apple Certification Authority and some Apple updates also:

```
SHA1 3B 16 6C 3B 7D C4 B7 51 C9 FE 2A FA B9 13 56 41 E3 88 E1 86
```

Comment: I had no idea this was even possible! :D Does Gatekeeper use these to check the downloaded packages when opening them?

Comment: @user216602 I think so ;-)

Answer (score 0):

In general when I get a site I'm unsure of I will go to the product.  Does it have a website on it. (normally this is present)

The 2nd part is the URL itself.  URL's are read opposite from the way english is read.  URL's are read from right to left starting with .com .org .net .gov etc.

so   "www.canon.com-ok.com"
is not taking you to canon.com but to com-ok.com

You didn't mention if you were in the US or EU.  EU devices may have different power requirements and model #'s from the manufacturer.

Comment: EU, but I checked the driver numbers on both US and Europe site, they were identical.